# ¿Como puedo hacer que una imagen colisione con imagenes de un mapa de tiles hecho con un arreglo? Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

soy nuevo en pygame y tengo una duda sobre las colisiones en pygame. Nose como hacer que una imagen colisione con una imagen que esta en un mapa (surface). Por ejemplo pude hacer que una imagen (jugador) colisione con otra imagen (jugador malo) pero cuando intento lo anteriormente dicho no me funciona.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
import pygame
import sys
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()
# --------------------------------------------------
# Definicion de Constantes Globales
run = True
nRes = (1012, 616)
FPS = 240
RELOJ = pygame.time.Clock()
nMAX_ROBOTS = 1
nMAX_MALOS = 1
nMx = nMy = 0
nT_HY = nT_WX = 44
# NOMBRE DE LA VENTANA
BLANCO = (255, 255, 255)
NEGRO = (0, 0, 0)
ROJO = (255, 0, 0)
CAFE = (90, 50, 15)
VERDE = (0, 255, 0)
# ICONO
icono = pygame.image.load("SpritesPython3/Triangle-PNG.png")

# ---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Carga imagenes y convierte formato pygame
# sFile -> Nombre del archivo grafico (BMP, JPEG, PNG, etc.)
# lTransparente -> Parametro logico que indica si la imagen a graficar
# tiene contornos o areas transparentes que se deben mostrar.
# Por defecto es FALSO. Es decir, se asume que la grafica es del tipo
# BLOCK sin contornos o areas trasparentes.
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------


def Load_Image(sFile, transp=False):
    try:
        image = pygame.image.load(sFile)
    except pygame.error as message:
        raise SystemExit(message)
    image = image.convert()
    if transp:
        color = image.get_at((0, 0))
        image.set_colorkey(color, RLEACCEL)
    return image


# ---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Inicializa PGs.-
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------


def Init_PyGame():
    pygame.init()
    pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)
    pygame.display.set_caption('PROYECT')
    pygame.display.set_icon(icono)
    return pygame.display.set_mode(nRes)


# ---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Inicializa Array de Sprites
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------

def Fig_Init():
    aImg = []
    # Verde                             0
    aImg.append(Load_Image('SpritesPython3/f7.png', False))
    # Celeste                           1
    aImg.append(Load_Image('SpritesPython3/f4.png', False))
    # Gris                              2
    aImg.append(Load_Image('SpritesPython3/f1.png', False))
    # Fondo Mouse                       3
    aImg.append(Load_Image('SpritesPython3/ff.png', True))
    return aImg

# ---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Clase Jugador 1
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------


class J1(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    # Sprite del jugador
    def __init__(self):
        # Heredamos el init de la clase Sprite de Pygame
        super().__init__()
        # Rectángulo (jugador)
        self.image = pygame.image.load(
            'SpritesPython3/SquareGreen.png').convert()
        # Obtiene el rectángulo (sprite)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        # Centra el rectángulo (sprite)
        self.rect.center = (100, 100)
        # Velocidad iniciales de J1
        self.v_x = 0
        self.v_y = 0

    def update(self):
        # Velocidad predeterminada cada vuelta del bucle
        self.v_x = 0
        self.v_y = 0
        # Se presiono una tecla?
        cKey = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if cKey[pygame.K_UP]:
            self.v_y -= 1
        if cKey[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            self.v_y += 1
        if cKey[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.v_x += 1
        if cKey[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.v_x -= 1
        # Actualiza velocidad/posición de J1
        self.rect.x += self.v_x
        self.rect.y += self.v_y
        # Establecer limites
        # Limite Superior
        if self.rect.top < 0:
            pygame.time.delay(1000)
            self.rect.center = (100, 100)
        # Limite Inferior
        if self.rect.bottom > nRes[1]:
            pygame.time.delay(1000)
            self.rect.center = (100, 100)
        # Limite Derecho
        if self.rect.right > nRes[0]:
            pygame.time.delay(1000)
            self.rect.center = (100, 100)
        # Limite Izquierdo
        if self.rect.left < 0:
            pygame.time.delay(1000)
            self.rect.center = (100, 100)

# ---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Clase Enemys
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------


class M1(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    # Sprite del jugador
    def __init__(self):
        # Heredamos el init de la clase Sprite de Pygame
        super().__init__()
        # Rectángulo (jugador)
        self.image = pygame.image.load(
            'SpritesPython3/SquareRed.png').convert()
        # Obtiene el rectángulo (sprite)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        # Centra el rectángulo (sprite)
        self.rect.center = (300, 300)

    def update(self):
        # Movimiento de M1
        self.rect.x += 1
        if self.rect.right > nRes[0]:
            self.rect.left = 0

# ---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Pinta Mapa
# Esta funcion pinta (grafica) en la Superficie principal la Superficie
# deseada en las coordenadas (X,Y)
# Los Tiles (Baldosas) tienen un tamano de 44x44 pixeles.
# El Mapa esta compuesto por 14 Filas y 23 Columnas
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------


def Pinta_Mapa():
    nX = nY = 0
    for nF in range(0, 14):
        for nC in range(0, 23):  # (x,y)
            sWin.blit(aSprt[aMapa[nF][nC]], (nX, nY))
            nX += 44
        nY += 44
        nX = 0
    return

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Mapa
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------


aMapa = [
    [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
]

# ------------------------------------------------------------
# Pinta la Posicion de la Mouse en Panta de PyGame
# ------------------------------------------------------------


def Pinta_Mouse():
    sWin.blit(aSprt[3], (nMx, nMy))
    return

# ------------------------------------------------------------
#
# ------------------------------------------------------------


sWin = Init_PyGame()
aSprt = Fig_Init()
# Grupo de sprites, instanciación del objeto jugador.
sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
enemigos = pygame.sprite.Group()
# Instanciaciones player
Player = J1()
sprites.add(Player)
# Instanciaciones enemy
Enemy = M1()
enemigos.add(Enemy)
# Bucle principal
while run:
    # --------------
    aEv = pygame.event.get()
    for e in aEv:
        if e.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if e.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
            nMx, nMy = e.pos  # Coordenada Mouse
        elif e.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:  # Evento de Tecla Presionada
            if e.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:  # Fue la tecla (key) ESC ?
                lOK = 0
            if e.key == pygame.K_s:  # Fue Key = S -> Salva en DISCO el Mapa.
                pygame.image.save(sWin, 'PantallazoPR2.jpg')
    # Actualización de sprites
    sprites.update()
    enemigos.update()
    # Colisiones entre sprites
    # (El que colisiona, el colisionado, )
    colision = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(Player, enemigos, False)
    if colision:
        pygame.time.delay(1000)
        Player.rect.center = (100, 100)
        Enemy.rect.center = (300, 300)
    # --------------

    # ---------------
    Pinta_Mapa()
    sprites.draw(sWin)
    enemigos.draw(sWin)
    Pinta_Mouse()
    # ---------------
    pygame.display.update()
    RELOJ.tick(FPS)
```

Como ven, ahí logre que 'player' colisione con 'enemigo' con la función "spritecollide()" , pero cuando intento hacer algo similar con esa función no me resulta.

aSprt[2] es un tile de color gris.

Y Básicamente quiero que al colisionar mi jugador (player) con los tiles grises (aSprt[2]) mi jugador vuelva a su posición inicial (self.rect.center = (100, 100))

El 'aSprt[2]' está agrupado en aMapa (en total 36 cuadraditos grises, son todos los '2')

Lo que intenté fue lo siguiente:

```
for i in aMapa:
    for j in i:
        if j == 2:
            j = aSprt[2]
            enemigos.add(j)
```

Pero al intentar eso me aparece el error:

AttributeError: 'pygame.Surface' object has no attribute 'add_internal'

Y esa es mi duda, nose como lograr esa colision. Nose si me explique bien.
Uso python 3.10.4

Comment: El problema se debe a que estás intentando añadir surfaces a un grupo de Sprites, donde se supone que solo deberían ser añadidos Sprites.

Comment: @DanteS. Gracias por comentar. Tendría que cambiar la forma en la que hice el mapa? O no? Entiendo el problema pero no sabría como resolverlo.

Comment: De nada! Tendrías que crear Sprites a partir de los tiles que te interese y luego añadirlos al grupo.

Comment: Gracias, lo intentaré.